# Firebase Crashlytics fails to report crash in Firebase Console

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I am currently trying to integrate Google's Firebase Crashlytics reporting functionality into our application. We currently use Fabric, but since Fabric is being deprecated in support of Firebase Crashlytics.

I followed the migration steps (migrating from Fabric to using Firebase Crashlytics). However, on testing the current implementation I get the following error

```
06-03 19:39:23.735  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.company.appa.pos/files/.com.google.firebase.crashlytics/report-persistence/sessions/5ED7DB3A027B00
01184FE3BB77B63DD3/user: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-03 19:39:23.735  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics:   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
06-03 19:39:23.735  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics:   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
06-03 19:39:23.735  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics:   at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.persistence.CrashlyticsReportPersistence.readTextFile(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0:470)
06-03 19:39:23.735  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics:   at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.persistence.CrashlyticsReportPersistence.synthesizeReport(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0:309
)
06-03 19:39:23.735  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics:   at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.persistence.CrashlyticsReportPersistence.finalizeReports(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0:197)
06-03 19:39:23.735  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics:   at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.SessionReportingCoordinator.finalizeSessions(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0:159)
06-03 19:39:23.735  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics:   at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsController.doCloseSessions(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0:867)
06-03 19:39:23.735  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics:   at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsController.doCloseSessions(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0:827)
06-03 19:39:23.735  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics:   at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsController$6.call(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0:407)
06-03 19:39:23.735  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics:   at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsController$6.call(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0:393)
06-03 19:39:23.735  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics:   at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker$3.then(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0:106)
06-03 19:39:23.735  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics:   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source)
06-03 19:39:23.735  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
06-03 19:39:23.735  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
06-03 19:39:23.735  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics:   at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0:60)
06-03 19:39:23.735  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics:   at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0:27)
06-03 19:39:23.735  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
06-03 19:39:23.735  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-03 19:39:23.735  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics:   at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
06-03 19:39:23.735  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics:   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
06-03 19:39:23.735  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics:   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
06-03 19:39:23.735  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics:   ... 16 more
06-03 19:39:23.800  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Opening a new session with ID 5ED7E04B031F-0002-184F-E3BB77B63DD3
06-03 19:39:23.823  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Send via DataTransport disabled. Removing DataTransport reports.
06-03 19:39:25.492  6223  9493 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Timeout exceeded while awaiting app exception callback from FA listener.
06-03 19:39:25.493  6223  6223 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics completed exception processing. Invoking default exception handler.
06-03 19:39:25.495  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Attempting to send crash report at time of crash...
06-03 19:39:25.508  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Adding single file 5ED7DB3A027B-0001-184F-E3BB77B63DD3.cls to report 5ED7DB3A027B-0001-184F-E3BB77B63DD3
06-03 19:39:25.510  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Sending report to: https://reports.crashlytics.com/spi/v1/platforms/android/apps/com.company.appb/reports
06-03 19:39:27.666  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Create report request ID: null
06-03 19:39:27.666  6223  6250 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Result was: 202
06-03 19:39:27.668  6223  6250 I FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics Reports Endpoint upload complete: 5ED7DB3A027B-0001-184F-E3BB77B63DD3
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebaser here -

Here's a link to a github issue that looks like yours: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1559

In [this comment](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1559#issuecomment), one of the engineers from Crashlytics explains that "if you're seeing a log entry for FileNotFoundException that ends in /user -- that is benign." So unless you're actually being blocked by this or something isn't working, you should be all set.

Comment: Yes, and we must ensure `Sending report to: https://reports.crashlytics.com/spi/v1/platforms/android/apps/com.example.myapp/reports` in the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Facing same issue in new Firebase Crashlytics. My suggestion to you is to roll back to previoud version of fabric crashlytics.

Comment: Any other suggestion ?